# Geoserver: How to enable REST Authentication filter chain to allow PUT/POST calls

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

As a followup of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255758/geoserver-rest-change-create-style-via-put-post-only-possible-when-user-is-assi) I am wondering how to enable a certain user to be able to place HTTP PUT/POST calls to /geoserver/rest/styles/ without granting the user admin rights or disabling chain security check under Authentication->Filter chain.

With my $geoserver_home/data/security/rest.properties settings being

```
/rest/**;GET=ROLE_REST_READ
/rest/**;POST,PUT,DELETE=ROLE_REST_WRITE
```

I assigned user 'chief' the roles 'ROLE_REST_READ' and 'ROLE_REST_WRITE'.

When doing PUT/POST calls with this credentials it will result in Status Code 405 NOT ALLOWED. GET calls however work fine. Using admin credentials or disabling REST chain security check PUT/POST calls work fine (Status Code 200). I tried changing the REST chain settings (check HTTP method, role filter) with no luck. Changing the admin role of the current role service 'default' from ROLE_ADMIN to ROLE_REST_WRITE also works, giving user chief complete admin right over the web interface however.

How/where can I edit the REST filter chain settings to not block PUT/POST calls? Please excuse me if I am missing some basic filter chain points here as I am pretty new to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but I ran into a similar issue on GeoServer 2.17.1; however, I also got an additional clue in the response:

```
405 Cannot edit global resource , full admin credentials required
```

ymmv, but I was able to resolve it by adding a workspace to the request and updating the rest.properties appropriately. For example:

- `rest/styles\?name\=my-new-style`
- `rest/workspaces/ws/styles\?name\=my-new-style`

### Full Example

#### rest.properties

```
/rest/workspaces/*/styles*;GET,POST,PUT=ROLE_REST_WRITE
/**;GET,POST,PUT,DELETE=ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR
```

#### CURL

```
curl -v -K geo-curl -X POST -T my-new-style.ysld \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/vnd.geoserver.ysld+yaml" \
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws/styles\?name\=my-new-style
```

#### Sources

- https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/styles.yaml